# TransferSpreadsheet dropping pseudo-duplicates

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010

I'm modifying an Access 2010 process that uses TransferSpreadsheet to import an Excel file to a temp table, clean the data, and export it. The Excel file is a list of UIDs, names, contact info, etc. Occasionally 1 UID will have 2 entries, as there are 2 email addresses. The issue is that the import will only keep the first of each record, when I need to preserve both. SQL And dummy data below:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM tmpTABLE")
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 9, "tmpTABLE", Me.txtFile, True
```

#### Patient FirstName LastName Salutation Email

1234567890 Bob Bobson NULL bbobson@bobco.com

1234567890 Bob Bobson NULL bbobson2@bobco.com

0987654321 Fran Frannie NULL ffrannie@fran.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the first column `Patient` in `tmpTABLE` is set as primary key (or with a unique index). So it can't have duplicate values, and drops those records.

Since you have fieldnames in your import file, you can add a new autonumber column to `tmpTABLE`, set this as primary key, and use the same code as before to import.

The new column won't be set from imported data, but automatically from the autonumber.

Comment: PK was exactly the issue. Thanks!